# Windows 10 Printer that Sends to Wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, hacks

Is there a way to "print to wordpress" from Windows (10) desktop? So lets say I am looking at a PDF and I want to create a new wordpress post from the PDF, I select print, select "wordpress printer" and a new blog post is automatically created with the PDF displayed?

Did some google research but didn't find anything promising.

Comment: Yes you could write a printer driver that actually just fired off a HTTP request with the necessary auth, but that's not a WordPress project, that's a Windows 10 driver project, and it's far from trivial

Comment: You will want to start here, it will give you a basic Windows Printer v4 driver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641620(v=vs.85).aspx Which you can then configure to communicate with a WordPress install using the REST API

Answer (score 1):

Not a print to Wordpress plugin as such, but this will import the PDF text into the editor.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/aspose-pdf-importer/

Or use a custom PHP class such as:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9423-PHP-Convert-PDF-to-HTML-using-Poppler.html

which will convert the pdf to html, hopefully with styles. You'd need to create a page template for the html if you want to change the entire layout of your page to reflect the PDF.  Though as you want them to be blog posts you're possibly stuck to having to use the editor, so trying to match the layout might not be ideal and the first suggestion, using a plugin to get the text, might be your best option without some clever custom coding.

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for I hope it's of some help!

Answer (score 0):

Sending data into WordPress via the WordPress API is relatively straight forward. The difficulty you'll have with this is around the OCR to pull the data from the scanned document along with creating a desktop application which connects to your scanner along which interprets & formats the data then posts this to the API. The WordPress side of this is straight forward.

Update;
To post to WordPress, use the WordPress JSON API Version 2, full documentation here, v2.wp-api.org. Nothing at the WordPress end is going to help you to send the data to WordPress, only how WordPress handles the data once it is received. You'll need a desktop application to do the first part of this process

Comment: I don't need to OCR the file being uploaded. Also, I know the difficulties, was looking for a suggestion for someone who has hopefully done it before (e.g. plugin).

Comment: To post to WordPress, use the WordPress JSON API Version 2, full documentation here, http://v2.wp-api.org/. Nothing at the WordPress end is going to help you to send the data to WordPress, only how WordPress handles the data once it is received. You'll need a desktop application to do the first part of this process.